# Automatic line break in asp.net textbox control

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario in my application, by saving a text of length 20000 chars without line break in between.When i retrieve the same to an asp.net textbox control my UI is stretching to the length of these 2000 chars in a single line . I have to wrap the text automatically inside text box.
  Can any one help to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.
Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [`columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.columns.aspx) property of the textbox to the maximum width you want.

There is also a [`width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.width.aspx) property that will also set the width to a specific pixel size.

In either case, you need to specify that the text in the textbox should wrap by setting the [`wrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.wrap.aspx) property to `true`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" columns="20" wrap="true" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting properties correctly on textbox didn't work. After searching through the web and not finding anything, I looked at the html source generated for the page. Turned out that one of the parent controls was emitting a 'white-space:nowrap' which got inherited by the textbox control. Added

```
style="white-space:normal"
```

to the textbox and voila that started making the wrap work.

Posting in case someone else runs into this.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I overlooked that.